# About Theorem 3.4 Hartshorne: detailed proof.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I propose a detailed version of part of the proof of ***Theorem 3.14*** from *Hartshorne*'s book *Algebraic Geometry*. The questions are inserted from time to time within the proof. Thanks for your patience.

***Notation*** Let $Y\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety. Letting $S=k[x_0,\dots, x_n]$ (equipped with the usual grading $S=\oplus_{r\ge 0} S_r$), there is a naturale grading on $S(Y)=S/I(Y)$ which is constructed as follows: for each integer $r\ge 0$ define $$S(Y)_r:=S_r/I(Y)_r:=\{f+I(Y)_r\;:\; f\in S_r\}$$ where $I(Y)_r=I(Y)\cap S_r.$

> **Theorem.** Let $Y\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety with homogeneous coordinate ring $S(Y)$. Then we have:
>
> $(a)\quad$ for any point $P\in Y$, let $\mathcal{m}_P\subseteq S(Y)$ denote the ideal generated by the set of all homogeneous elements $f\in S(Y)$ such that $f(P)=0$. Then $\mathcal{O}_P=S(Y)_{(\mathcal{m}_P)}$;
>
> $(b)\quad$ $K(Y)\cong S(Y)_{((0))}$

***Proof.*** Let $U_i\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n$ be the open set defined by $x_i\ne 0$ and set $Y_i:= Y\cap U_i$. We may consider $Y_i$ as an affine variety. We can construct a natural isomorphism $$\varphi_i^*\colon A(Y_i)\to S(Y)_{(x_i)}$$ as $$\varphi_i^*\bigg(f(y_1,\dots, y_{i-i},1, y_i, \dots, y_n)+I(Y_i)\bigg)=\frac{f(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_r}{x_i^r+I(Y)_r},$$ where $f\in S_r$.

$(b)\quad$ Let $P\in Y$ and chose any $i$ so that the $i-$th coordinate of $P$ is non-zero. Then $P\in Y\cap U_i$. We may write $P=[a_0:\dots: a_{i-1}:1:a_i:\dots: a_n]$. Set $P_0:=(a_0,\dots, a_{i-1}, a_{i+1},\dots, a_n)=\varphi_i(P)$, the corresponding point in the affine space.

Denote with $\mathcal{m'}_{P_0}$ the maximal ideal of $A(Y_i)$ corresponding to $P_0$. More precisely, $$\mathcal{m'}_{P_0}=\bigg\{g+I(Y_i)\in A(Y_i)\;:\; g(P_0)=0\bigg\}.$$ It's easy to prove that: $$\boxed{\varphi_i^*(\mathcal{m'}_{P_0})=\mathcal{m}_P\cdot S(Y)_{(x_i)}}$$ Recall that the product in the right of the above equation is interpreted in the localization as follows (with the natural induced grading on the quotient ring $S(Y)=S/I(Y))$
$$\mathcal{m}_p\cdot S(Y)_{(x_i)}=\bigg\{\frac{f(x_0\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_r}{x_i^r+I(Y)_r}\;:\; f+I(Y)_r\in\mathcal{m}_P\cap S(Y)_r\;\text{for same}\; r\ge 0\bigg\}.$$

Using this isomorphism, we then have the isomorphism of the localizations $$A(Y_i)_{\mathcal{m'}_{P_0}}\cong \big(S(Y)_{(x_i)}\big)_{\mathcal{m}_P\cdot S(Y)_{(x_i)}}$$

> **Question 1.** I believe that the last isomorphism can be obtained from exercise number 4 on page 44 of *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyay - MacDonald, is that so?

We need to argue that $$\big(S(Y)_{(x_i)}\big)_{\mathcal{m}_P\cdot S(Y)_{(x_i)}}\cong S(Y)_{(\mathcal{m}_P)}\tag1$$

> **Question2.** Why $(1)$ is not usual transitivity of localizations?

A typical element in $\big(S(Y)_{(x_i)}\big)_{\mathcal{m}_P\cdot S(Y)_{(x_i)}}$ is of the form

$$\frac{\frac{f+I(Y)_{s+r}}{x_i^{r+s}+I(Y)_{s+r}}}{\frac{g+I(Y)_r}{x_i^r+I(Y)_r}}\equiv \frac{f+I(Y)_{s+r}}{x_i^sg+I(Y)_{s+r}}$$ where $g+I(Y)_r\notin\mathcal{m}_p\cap S(Y)_r$, and the identification takes place in the quotient field of $S(Y)$. Now since $x_i^s+I(Y)_s\notin \mathcal{m}_p\cap S(Y)_s$ it follows that the product $x_i^sg +I(Y)_{s+r}\notin\mathcal{m}_p\cap S(Y)_{s+r}$. So the element on the right is a degree $0$ element of the localization

$$S(Y)_{\mathcal{m}_P}=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\big(S(Y)_{\mathcal{m}_P}\big)_n$$ where

$$\big(S(Y)_{\mathcal{m}_P}\big)_n=\bigg\{\frac{p+I(Y)_{n+r}}{q+I(Y)_r}\;:\; q+I(Y)_r\notin \mathcal{m}_P\cap S(Y)_r\;\text{for same}\; r\ge 0\bigg\}.$$ This proves that $$A(Y_i)_{\mathcal{m'}_{P_0}}\cong (S(Y)_{\mathcal{m}_p})_0=S(Y)_{(\mathcal{m}_P)}$$

$(b)\quad$ Observe that $K(Y)\cong K(Y_i)$. The final part is to show that $$K(Y_i)\cong S(Y)_{((0))}.$$ We have already obtained the isomorphism $\varphi_i^*\colon A(Y_i)\to S(Y)_{(x_i)}$. Extending this isomorpgism to $\tilde{\varphi_i^{*}}$ on the quotient fields fo both the sides we get $$\tilde{\varphi_i^*}\bigg(\frac{f(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1},1, y_i, \dots, y_n)+I(Y_i)}{g(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1},1, y_i, \dots, y_n)+I(Y_i)}\bigg)=\frac{\frac{f(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_r}{x_i^r+I(Y)_r}}{\frac{g(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_s}{x_i^s+I(Y)_s}}=\frac{x_i^s f(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_{r+s}}{x_i^rg(x_0, \dots, x_n)+I(Y)_{r+s}}$$

In the denominator of the last expression above we have $g(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_s\ne 0$ So to make sense of this, we need $x_i^r+I(Y)_r\ne 0$ as well. Since $I(Y)$ is a homogeneous prime ideal, this is violated only if $x_i\in I(Y)$. I have proved that $x_i\in I(Y)$ is equivalent to $Y_i=\emptyset$, which is absurd according to our choise of $U_i$.

Finally, notice that the element in the image of $\tilde{\varphi_i^*}$ in above are elements of $S(Y)_{((0))}$.

> **Question 3** It remains to show that every element of $S(Y)_{((0))}$ is also an image of an element of $K(Y_i)$. How can I show this?

***My Solution for question 3.***

A typical element in $S(Y)_{((0))}$ is of the form $$\frac{f(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_r}{g(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_r},$$ where $f+I(Y)_r\in S(Y)_r$ and $g+I(Y)_r\notin S(Y)_r\cap (0)$. Let us consider the dehomogenized of $f$ and $g$: $$f(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1}, 1, y_i,\dots, y_n)\quad\text{and}\quad g(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1}, 1, y_i,\dots, y_n),$$ where $\deg f(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1}, 1, y_i,\dots, y_n)= \deg g(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1}, 1, y_i,\dots, y_n) = r$, results

$$\begin{split}\tilde{\varphi_i^*}\bigg(\frac{f(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1},1, y_i, \dots, y_n)+I(Y_i)}{g(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1},1, y_i, \dots, y_n)+I(Y_i)}\bigg)=&\frac{\frac{f(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_r}{x_i^r+I(Y)_r}}{\frac{g(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_r}{x_i^r+I(Y)_r}}\\
=\frac{f(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_{r}}{g(x_0, \dots, x_n)+I(Y)_{r}}\end{split}$$

The above happens just in case $x_i\nmid f$ and $x_i \nmid g$.

Suppose now that $x_i\mid f(x_0,\dots, x_n)$ and that $x_i\nmid g(x_0,\dots, x_n)$

We denote by $h(x_0,\dots, x_n)$ the homogenized polynomial of $f(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1},1,\,y_i,\dots, y_n)$, then $h\in S_{\deg f}$, then

$$
\begin{split}
\tilde{\varphi_i^*}\bigg(\frac{f(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1},1, y_i, \dots, y_n)+I(Y_i)}{g(y_1,\dots, y_{i-1},1, y_i, \dots, y_n)+I(Y_i)}\bigg)=
\frac{\frac{h(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_{\deg f}}{x_i^{\deg f}+I(Y)_{\deg f}}}{\frac{g(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_r}{x_i^r+I(Y)_r}}=&\frac{x_i^{r-\deg f} h(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_{r}}{g(x_0, \dots, x_n)+I(Y)_{r}}\\
=&\frac{f(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_r}{g(x_0,\dots, x_n)+I(Y)_r}
\end{split}
$$